# ListView requestLayout() warning

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview, android-cursoradapter

I have a `ListView` and which contains Items made of a `RelativeLayout`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.app.FragmentList">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/ListView01"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
        android:fastScrollAlwaysVisible="true"
        android:smoothScrollbar="false"
        android:scrollingCache="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The Items:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Erika Mustermann"
        android:id="@+id/textViewName"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-3dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Company Inc."
        android:id="@+id/textViewCompany"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:textColor="#6b6b6b"
        android:textSize="13dp"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout_one"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="Work: "
                android:id="@+id/NumLabel0"
                android:textColor="#6b6b6b" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="+49-1234-1234567"
                android:id="@+id/textViewPhoneWork"
                android:textColor="#6b6b6b" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout_two"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout_one">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="Mobile: "
                android:id="@+id/NumLabel1"
                android:textColor="#6b6b6b" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="+49-1234-1234567"
                android:id="@+id/textViewPhoneMobile"
                android:textColor="#6b6b6b" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The `ListView` gets a `CursorAdapter` which with a ViewHolder pattern, its `bindView()`:

```
@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    holder.nameText.setText(cursor.getString(2) + ", " + cursor.getString(1));
    Cursor values = getContactValues(cursor.getString(0));
    values.moveToLast();
    if (values.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            if (values.getPosition() == 0) {
                holder.type0Text.setText(replaceType(values.getString(0), context) + ": ");
                holder.num0Text.setText(values.getString(1));
            } else {
                holder.type1Text.setText(replaceType(values.getString(0), context) + ": ");
                holder.num1Text.setText(values.getString(1));
            }
        } while (values.getPosition() < 2 && values.moveToNext());

        int pos = values.getPosition();
        if (pos == 1) {
            holder.type1Text.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.num1Text.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        if (values.getPosition() == 2) {
            holder.type1Text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.num1Text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
    values.close();

}
```

its newView:

```
@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = View.inflate(context, R.layout.contact_item, null);
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.nameText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
    holder.type0Text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.NumLabel0);
    holder.type1Text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.NumLabel1);
    holder.num0Text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewPhoneWork);
    holder.num1Text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewPhoneMobile);
    view.setTag(holder);
    return view;
}
```

the creation of the `CursorAdapter` and its constructor:

```
cadapter = new ContactListCursorAdapter(view.getContext(), namesCursor, 0, readDB, arg2 + 1);
```

and:

```
ContactListCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags, SQLiteDatabase readDB, int _ID) {
super(context, c, flags);
this.readDB = readDB;
Cursor tmpc = readDB.query(SQLiteHelper.TABLE, new String[]{SQLiteHelper._ID}, SQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(_ID)}, null, null, null, null);
tmpc.moveToFirst();
this.list = tmpc.getString(tmpc.getColumnIndex(SQLiteHelper._ID));
}
```

Whenever the `View` is displayed or updated I get a warning ot the type:

```
14:25:33.543  27597-27597/com.app W/View﹕ requestLayout() improperly called by android.widget.TextView{41d97830 V.ED.... ......ID 24,24-364,105 #7f09003f app:id/textViewName} during layout: running second layout pass
14:25:33.543  27597-27597/com.app W/View﹕ requestLayout() improperly called by android.widget.TextView{41d988b8 V.ED.... ......ID 0,0-165,52 #7f090043 app:id/NumLabel0} during layout: running second layout pass
14:25:33.543  27597-27597/com.app W/View﹕ requestLayout() improperly called by android.widget.TextView{41d98ce0 V.ED.... ......ID 165,0-488,52 #7f090044 app:id/textViewPhoneWork} during layout: running second layout pass
14:25:33.543  27597-27597/com.app W/View﹕ requestLayout() improperly called by android.widget.TextView{41d9b380 V.ED.... ......ID 24,24-467,105 #7f09003f app:id/textViewName} during layout: running second layout pass
14:25:33.543  27597-27597/com.app W/View﹕ requestLayout() improperly called by android.widget.TextView{41d9c408 V.ED.... ......ID 0,0-165,52 #7f090043 app:id/NumLabel0} during layout: running second layout pass
14:25:33.543  27597-27597/com.app W/View﹕ requestLayout() improperly called by android.widget.TextView{41d9c830 V.ED.... ......ID 165,0-488,52 #7f090044 app:id/textViewPhoneWork} during layout: running second layout pass
```

I have no clue where this error happens... and why.

It also seems like `com.android.contacts` is suffering the from same problem.

```
06-16 15:12:10.113  27522-27522/com.android.contacts W/View﹕ requestLayout() improperly called by android.widget.TextView{41ed52f8 V.ED.... ......ID 216,90-936,149 #7f0c000e app:id/cliv_name_textview} during layout: running second layout pass
```

Comment: it looks a bit like @596041 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23805472 has the same problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, I know that this is an old thread, but if anyone else has the same problem it was caused in my case due to fastScrollEnabled.

To get rid of it just **remove**

```
    android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
    android:fastScrollAlwaysVisible="true"
```

Hope it helps anyone.

Comment: wow, I would never have thought that the layout options caused the errors but I need fastscrooling, so this is just a part of the solution

Comment: this is the cause though, it might lead to the right solution, but I cannot really find anything else that is needed for fastscrolling -.- I will simply continue to ignore the message, as long as there is no proper solution

Comment: I think it is because the fastscroller draws above the listview items, or if you make the scroller to draw outside it it shrinks it, so in a way it causes conflict with the list view or its elements who has a match parent property, still I don't think it does much harm to the performance in any way.

Answer (score 3):

Problem is in your newView Method below line:

```
 View view = View.inflate(context, R.layout.contact_item, null);
```

Replace above line with

```
LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
     View view = inflater.inflate(context, R.layout.contact_item, null);
```

Thats it...

Comment: hmm I tried that already, it does not work, it results in the same error, at least. 
    LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_item, null);

Comment: inflater.inflate(context, R.layout.contact_item, null) cannot be resolved since there is no method with those paramters :(